# I create an object in one method and I'm trying to use it in other methods

Tags: java

So my code looks something like this:

```
class Pozadina extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
  ArrayList<Pozicija> list;
  public Pozicija _11;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

                ArrayList<Pozicija> list=new ArrayList<Pozicija>();
                Pozicija _11=new Pozicija();
                _11.setCoords(korak,korak);
                list.add(_11);

                //lots of drawing here

                for (Pozicija p:list) {
                    if (p.getBelongsTo()==1){
                        g.setColor(Color.blue);
                    }

                    g.fillOval(p.getX(), p.getY(), 20, 20;
                    g.setColor(Color.black);
                }//for loop
       }//paintComponent method
```

And then I have main that looks like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(630,630);
            Pozadina pozadina= new Pozadina();
            frame.getContentPane().add(pozadina);
            frame.addMouseListener(pozadina);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
```

And on click event that looks like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            _11.setPlayer1();
            pozadina.repaint();
        }
```

So the problem is that I am creating _11 object in graphics, so mouse Clicked method returns null pointer exception. I do have Pozicija _11; set as instance variable of class, but it doesn't work. I am trying to figure out how to avoid this, but I am fairly new to java and I ran out of ideas.

EDIT: I am getting Null Point Exception error even when i do it like this. :S

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                /*_11.setPlayer1();
                pozadina.repaint();*/
            }
```

And its telling me its line "/*_11.setPlayer1();". No idea whats going on.

I did try 2 of suggestions posted, i always had _11 as instance variable in a class, i just didn't copy it here.

EDIT2: First of all, thanks for all the answers. :D I've updated my code to show that I have both list and _11 as instance variables, it was always like this, I just didn't copy it when I was copying my code. Please check last edit, it may help you out. I am assuming that I am getting errors because of something else, because even when I put comments on part that I tought was causing errors, I still get errors. Thanks.

Comment: Both `list` and `_11` in `paintComponent` are local variables: as soon as you exit that method, they become inaccessible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the _11 in the class enviroment like this or you are unable to reach a variable defined in a method from another method if not directly passed as input.

```
class Pozadina extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

     public Pozicija _11;

     public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

            ArrayList<Pozicija> list=new ArrayList<Pozicija>();
            _11=new Pozicija();
            _11.setCoords(korak,korak);
            list.add(_11);

            //lots of drawing here

            for (Pozicija p:list) {
                if (p.getBelongsTo()==1){
                    g.setColor(Color.blue);
                }

                g.fillOval(p.getX(), p.getY(), 20, 20;
                g.setColor(Color.black);
            }//for loop
      }//paintComponent method
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where `_11` is declared as an instance variable but i DO see where you declare a `_11` in your `paintComponent` method

```
Pozicija _11=new Pozicija();
_11.setCoords(korak,korak);
list.add(_11);
```

Now if that doesn't make your code not compile, than the only logical conclusion is that It puts any existing instance variable `_11` out of scope for the remainder of that method, and It won't be changed if you do anything to it that method.

---

in order for it to be an instance field, it has to be declared outside your method like so

```
class Pozadina extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    public /*or private*/ Pozicija _11;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        ArrayList<Pozicija> list=new ArrayList<Pozicija>();
        _11=new Pozicija();
        _11.setCoords(korak,korak);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instansiate your _11 variable in your Pozina constructor and remove it from paint() method.

Your code may look like something this:

```
class Pozadina extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    private Pozicija _11;
    ArrayList<Pozicija> list=new ArrayList<Pozicija>();            

    public Pozadina(){
        _11=new Pozicija();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        _11.setCoords(korak,korak);
        list.add(_11);

        //lots of drawing here

        for (Pozicija p:list) {
            if (p.getBelongsTo()==1){
                g.setColor(Color.blue);
            }

         g.fillOval(p.getX(), p.getY(), 20, 20;
         g.setColor(Color.black);
            }//for loop
   }//pa

     public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         _11=new Pozicija();
         _11.setPlayer1();
         pozadina.repaint();
     }
}
```

Comment: You missed to add `Pozadina()` before `_11.setCoords(korak,korak);`.

Comment: @araknoid I think it should not be there. As far as I understand from the code, he tries to instantiate a new object when mouse clicked, and add and process it in the paintComponent method. I've edited the code